# DataSet.GetXML disable auto escape

Tags: vb.net, datatable, dataset

How to prevent `DataSet.GetXml` from converting `<` and `>` to `&lt;` and `&gt;`?

Comment: You cannot tell it to produce invalid XML.

Comment: @SLaks: But it also escape XML tags... `<NewDataSet>` => `&lt;NewDataSet&gt;`

Comment: Where do you put the result of `GetXml`?  A variable? TextBox? File? Also we could use an example of the XML it generates...